Transfer Learning in EfficientNet for Binary Classification Task stuck at 50%
I've been trying to do transfer learning in EfficientNet in a binary classification task.
My directory structure looks like this:
training
├── label0
└── label1

validation
├── label0
└── label1

and I use this to create the image datagen:
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=30,           
    width_shift_range=0.0,       
    height_shift_range=0.0,
    shear_range=0.0,            
    zoom_range=0.0,              
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest'
)
no augmentations are applied
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'training',
    target_size=(240, 240),     
    batch_size=128,               
    class_mode='binary',          # Binary classification
    shuffle=True
)

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'validation', 
    target_size=(240, 240),
    batch_size=128,
    class_mode='binary',
    shuffle=True
)

With an output of :
Found 19747 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 4938 images belonging to 2 classes.

This is the code for building the model:
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.applications import EfficientNetB1
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import layers

NUM_CLASSES = 2
IMG_SIZE = 240
size = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)

def build_model():
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3))
    
    model = EfficientNetB1(include_top=False, input_tensor=inputs, weights="imagenet")

    model.trainable = False
    
    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(name="avg_pool")(model.output)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    # x = layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(x)
    # top_dropout_rate = 0.2
    # x = layers.Dropout(top_dropout_rate, name="dropout")(x)
    # outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", name="pred")(x)
    outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", name="pred")(x)
    
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs, name="EfficientNet")
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4)
    model.compile(
        optimizer=optimizer,
        loss="binary_crossentropy",
        metrics=["accuracy"]
    )
    
    return model

you can see that I'm trying lots of things just to make something work but to no avail. I set model.trainable to False since I am following this implementation on transfer learning. I still haven't finished the first step. I was planning to move on to the unfreezing once I reached 60-70% but I can't even make it to 52%.
Here is how I start the training:
model = build_model()
epochs = 50
hist = model.fit(train_generator, 
                 epochs=epochs, 
                 steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator), 
                 validation_data=validation_generator,
                 validation_steps=len(validation_generator))

and the accuracy and val_accuracy are always almost 50% at the first ten epochs, which is no more than a random guessing.
I tried lowering or increasing the learning rate (1e-1 to 1e-6), the batch size (32 - 256), adding dropouts (0.1 - 0.5), adding relu layers (32 - 128), and making sure the images are in the right class. What can I do to make the model really learn?

If you are getting a training/validation accuracy of 50% it's possible that your network is not learning anything and it is just basically guessing. You won't get an accuracy of 0% because this is binary classification. Maybe the problem is in your architecture priors.

Further reading: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/611948/a-binary-classifier-with-accuracy-below-50-and-similar-situations

In Your code You use line:
model.trainable = False

This line means that your model can't be trained. If you want do transfer learning You have to unfreeze some layers.
Some example how to unfreeze last 2 layers, try to experiment with different values:
# Unfreeze the top layers of the base model
for layer in base_model.layers[-2:]:  
    if not isinstance(layer, layers.BatchNormalization):
        layer.trainable = True
    else:
        layer.trainable = False  

BatchNormalization  layers are frozen because for small dataset it may cause problems with convergence (values in this layer will be unstable).

Following the implementation here, it says:

The first step to transfer learning is to freeze all layers and train only the top layers,

and

The second step is to unfreeze a number of layers and fit the model using smaller learning rate.

So I thought the model will still learn despite some frozen layers. I will try to unfreeze some layers immediately and see if it results to anything significant.

it doesn't do anything. the training and validation accuracy is still around 50%. Are there any things that I might be missing?
